# How to insert a text into a sprite in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, Team, Position):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))

        self.red = (255, 0, 0)
        self.blue = (0, 0, 255)

        self.Team = Team
        self.Position = Position
        self.CurrentPosition = ""
        self.PlayerName = self.PlayerFinder('Name')
        if self.PlayerName is None:
            if self.Position == 'LW':
                self.Position = 'LM'
            elif self.Position == 'RW':
                self.Position = 'RM'
            self.PlayerName = self.PlayerFinder('Name')
        self.Nationality = ""
        self.Pace = ""
        self.Shoot = ""
        self.Pass = ""
        self.Dribble = ""
        self.GKDive = ""
        self.Reflex = ""
        # Player
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def DrawPlayerShape(self, co_ordinate, colouropt):
        self.CurrentPosition = co_ordinate
        # Colour option
        colour = ""
        if colouropt == 'R':
            colour = self.red
        elif colouropt == 'B':
            colour = self.blue

        # Player's shape as a sprite
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect.center = co_ordinate

        # Player's football position shown in the shape
        if self.Position == 'CDM':  # this ensures that they will fit inside the player shape
        text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 11).render(self.Position, True, (
            0, 0, 0))
        else:
            text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 15).render(self.Position, True, (
            0, 0, 0))
        self.image.blit(text_type, self.image)

st = Player()
st.DrawPlayerShape()
```

I have tried to add text to my sprite, but it does not work. The closest I have gotten to it, is I managed to write text, but it was underneath the sprite. How do I add text to the sprite which will stay there, even if it moves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.image.blit(text_type, self.image)` makes no sense because the second argument of [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) must be a tuple with the coordinates or a rectangle. If you want to put the text in the center of the *Surface*, you have to get the bounding rectangle of the text *Surface* and set the center of the rectangle with the center of the target *Surface*. Use the rectangle to `blit` the text on the *Surface*:

```py
image_center = self.image.get_rect().center
self.image.blit(text_type, text_type.get_rect(center = image_center))
```